# Getting the RSS of a model using k fold cross validation without using any packages in R

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am using 10-fold cross validation and regsubsets function from Leaps package for best subset selection. I want to calculate the RSS after fitting my model. I do not want to use any packages for this 10-fold cross validation. I suppose we cannot use the predict function for an object of rgsubsets. So I tried to calculate the rss of a my model using the following code but there's an error.

```
      mydata <- Hitters[sample(nrow(Hitters)),]

      folds <- cut(seq(1, nrow(mydata)), breaks = 10, labels = F)

      for (i in 1:10) {

            testindex <- which(folds == i)
            testdata <- mydata[testindex,]
            traindata <- mydata[ - testindex,]

  #there may be an error after this


            best.fits11 <- regsubsets(Salary ~ ., data = traindata, nvmax=19)
            test[i]<-coef(best.fits11, id = 19) * testdata
            train[i]<-traindata
            }
    for (i in 1:10) { 
    err.rss <-mean((test[i]-train[i])^2 )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let consider you have displayed the code exactly the same as you written while you get this error.

There is some clear bug in your code.

1. what is `test[i]`. What is the dimension of `test[i]`
2. same for `train[i]`.
3. Let consider both the `train` and `test` are a similar matrix. Which I highly doubt according to your syntax.
4. Now about calculating RSS. the calculation will work only if you represent `test` and `train` as the vector of the same length. So, there is no issue in the definition.

please clarify about the dimnesion of `train` and `test` data so that I could help you further.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I am using the dataset Hitters from the package ISLR . There are 20 columns in the dataset out of which 19 are predictors and salary is the response. The algorithm is to be run for 10 iterations and at each iteration train[i] and test[i] is to be computed so that RSS can be calculated. I want to score my testdata using the estimates from the traindata at each iteration but my code                                 test[i]<-coef(best.fits11, id = 19) * testdata                                              is perhaps wrong